# Java image wont move on mouse click?

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface

I haven't looked at the code for this little game I made a while ago, and now all of the sudden the image won't move up when I click it?

I know the clicks are being called because the counter goes up. But the image won't move up. Any help is appreciated.

Batman class below

```
package Clicky;

import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class Batman
{ 
private String batz = "batbomb.png";

private int x;
private int y;
private Image image;
private boolean visible;

public Batman()
{
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(batz));
image = ii.getImage();
visible = true;
    x = 145;
    y = 620;
}

public int getX() { return x; }

public int getY() { return y; }

public Image getImage() { return image; }


public boolean isVisible()
{
    return visible;
}

public void setVisible(boolean visible)
{
    this.visible = visible;
}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
       int button = MouseEvent.BUTTON1;
       if (button == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED)
       {
          y -= 1;
       }
}
}
```

Where everything is drawn here

```
package Clicky;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Clicky extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
private Batman bat;
private Timer timer;
private int clicks = 0;
private boolean visible;

public Clicky() {

    addMouseListener(new TAdapter());
    setFocusable(true);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setDoubleBuffered(true);

    timer = new Timer(5, this);
    timer.start();

    bat = new Batman();
}
public int getClickCount()
{
    return clicks;
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2d.drawString("Clicks: " + getClickCount(), 10, 50);
    g2d.drawRect(150, 70, 200, 600);
    g2d.drawImage(bat.getImage(), bat.getX(), bat.getY(), this);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    g.dispose();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    repaint();  
}

private class TAdapter extends MouseAdapter
{
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        e.getClickCount();
         clicks = clicks + 1;  
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I don't see the code where you display the image

Comment: Your code is confusing. Where is there a MouseListener? What is it being added to? Why compare if MOUSE_CLICKED == BUTTON1. They'll never be equal as far as I understand these constants.

Comment: An out of context code snippet isn't going to allow use to have any hope in knowing why this won't work.  How is it painted?  How is `mouseClicked` called?  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I will add the other class. Sorry about that.

Comment: No offense, I hardly think you need 200 fps...seriously...; don't dispose of a `Graphics` context you didn't create. `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();` probably shouldn't be done within a `paint` method

Comment: Most of that code is the framework i've always used based off of a zetcode example. It's always worked so I never changed it. As for FPS, I didn't even know it was that high. I haven't touched Java in a while.

Comment: *"based off of a zetcode example"* then either the example is wrong or you've copied to wrong.  disposing of a `Graphics` context could prevent it from painting other content in the future, the Mac OS is good at this...

Answer (score 3):

Your Batman `mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)` method never gets called (if I'm wrong, please show me where). But even if it did, your `MOUSE_CLICKED == BUTTON1` boolean check would always be false, since BUTTON1 and MOUSE_CLICKED are both constants and equal to different things, 1 and 500 respectively, and this will make sure that the if block never worked.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I saw what you mentioned and fixed it. Much appreciated.